# Parse Push: Subscribe Android app to more than one Parse app

Tags: android, parse-platform

Is it possible to subscribe an Android app to more than one Parse app?

In [Parse.com](http://www.parse.com), I have 2 apps (with its own keys). I'm developing an Android app that needs "to be initialized" to these 2 Parse apps, to receive pushes from them. Something like:

```
Parse.initialize(context, PARSE_APP1_ID, PARSE_APP1_KEY);
Parse.initialize(context, PARSE_APP2_ID, PARSE_APP2_KEY);
```

Is this possible?

I want this beacuse one of these Parse app is a "general notifier" for all my apps, and the other one is the app concrete backend/notifier.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  The methods to interact with parse.com do not provide any way to specify which app to use, which means they can't target different apps.